# Checking the value of a regsitry value in java script

Tags: java, install4j

I have a script in my installer that is checking for the existance of a registry key.

```
Util.showWarningMessage("Here");

Integer xx = (Integer)WinRegistry.getValue(RegistryRoot.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "Software\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\VisualStudio\\11.0\\VC\\Runtimes\\x86", "Installed");

Util.showWarningMessage("Here 2");

if (xx == 1) {
    Util.showWarningMessage("return 1");
}
else{
     Util.showWarningMessage("here 1");
}

return true;
```

The script compiles, but when I run the installer I see the first 2 warning messages but not the ones within the if statement. It also seems that the script is returning false(this is a condition statement to see if a certain component is installed).
When I remove the if statement the final return reached as expected.

I would be grateful if someone could explain what is wrong

Thanks in advance

Comment: That's Java, not Javascript

Answer (score 0):

Probably xx is null and the unboxing throws an exception. Try this:

```
Util.showWarningMessage("xx = " + xx);
```

to check the value of xx.